# Is there a way to approximate the pixel width of a Pandas DataFrame Column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pixel

I am trying to figure out how to automatically size a column (in pixels) in a grid widget, based on the data within a dataframe column. I was thinking about:

1) Getting the max number of characters:
       df.col1.map(lambda x: len(x)).max()

2) Finding the average width of a character and multiplying

But I thought someone smarter might have figured out something better.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated!

Comment: This will largely depend on your environment - your font, font size, text editor, screen resolution, whether you're running Python on a regular terminal vs IPython shell vs Pycharm vs Jupyter... Different environments have different out-of-the-box formatting for pandas DataFrames.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never I guess ;)

You can now set the *col_space** argument of `.to_html()`:

```
df.to_html(col_space='75px')
```

**The minimum width of each column in CSS length units. **An int is assumed to be px units**.*

For further information: [pandas.DataFrame.to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)